# How does one find an academic career coach?

Tags: job-search, job

Inquiring for a client with a PhD (public policy/labor studies) who has been hunting for a tenure-track position for 4 years (I'm an editor). Like many emerging scholars, she works at several adjunct positions each year. She has been very active in research and publishing, has won several grants since getting her PhD, and has applied for 50 jobs, resulting in 3 (unsuccessful) interviews. At this point she would like to find a career coach who specializes in working with academics in the North American market (Canada would be good, but perhaps not strictly necessary). Our google search for a coach hasn't turned up anyone so far. We investigated the website and book of a well-known coach and found that the information was readily available elsewhere, leading us to conclude that the person's high fee would not be a good investment. Any tips for finding and working with an academic job coach?

Comment: I bet this will be closed as shopping, but I am would recommend Karen Kelsky.

Comment: Usually, the career coaches in academia are the PhD advisor and the supervisors of subsequent postdocs. She _did_ ask for advice to them, didn't she?

Comment: I think the closest thing to what you are looking for in academia is what are called mentors.  These are usually people you know personally, but there are also some programs.  I don't know what's available in her field, but for instance the Association for Women in Math has a mentoring program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, she has already talked to her PhD advisor and postdoc supervisors. She's looking for someone who can look at her application documents, figure out what more she can do with them to stand out, and identify any weaknesses that are preventing her from getting interviews. Also possibly an interview coach.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The question implies there are not postdoc advisors and the PhD advisor is not competent.

Answer (score 3):

The only service I heard is "the professor is in" I watched some of their live Facebook videos and learn a lot. Even asked question in here relating their comments about job interview.
Also they provide couching and help with cover letter and statements for possition application with special emphasis on diversity. 
Some members of Academia.stackexchange find them controversial due to unorthodox views on STEM field. But since OP friend is from humanities and whole team is more from that background I highly recommend them.

Comment: Why do you think that business have views on STEM?  They're blatantly social science/humanities oriented.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist in my experience very contraversal. According to them, we are the one to easiest find job. And they claim most of STEM graduates are mediocre.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I think they watch field as easy